# ¿Como saber en que año se hicieron las mayores ventas en SQL?

Tags: sql

Hoy vengo con una duda, acerca de como contar años de una entrada con formato datetime.

Intente hacerlo con count(Fecha), pero como son Fechas diferentes solamente suma 1 por cada una, entonces, lo que quiero hacer es que sume un año en lugar de una fecha especifica. Ejemplo:
La lista con mi actual código hace esto.

| Nombre | Fecha | Repetido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2018-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2018-04-23 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2018-04-17 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2018-01-08 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A | 2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 | 1 |

Yo necesito, que lo haga de esta manera.
[image: Ejemplo]

Este es mi codigo

```
select Producto.Nombre, Ventas.Fecha, count(Ventas.Fecha)  as Repetido from Cliente

inner join Ventas on Cliente.id_Cliente = Ventas.id_Cliente
inner join Items on Ventas.id_Venta = Items.id_Venta
inner join Producto on Items.id_Producto = Producto.id_Producto 

where Items.id_Producto = 680
group by Producto.Nombre, Ventas.Fecha
order by Ventas.Fecha desc
```

Como datos adicionales, `Items.id_producto = 680` es el identificador para `REG. VELOCIDAD MOTOR CC 18-24V 6A`.
Trato de buscar una forma de reducir el formato datetime de Fecha para que solo muestre los años y esos años los cuente en un count.

Comment: Por favor, especifica qué motor de SQL estás utilizando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la función `year()`.

```
select Producto.Nombre, year(Ventas.Fecha), count(*) as Repetido from Cliente

inner join Ventas on Cliente.id_Cliente = Ventas.id_Cliente
inner join Items on Ventas.id_Venta = Items.id_Venta
inner join Producto on Items.id_Producto = Producto.id_Producto 

where Items.id_Producto = 680
group by Producto.Nombre, year(Ventas.Fecha)
order by Repetido desc
```

Esta función sirve para **MySQL**, **SQL Server** y **MariaDB**.

Comment: En efecto, al parecer la función year() es lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta!

Comment: `year()` no existe en muchos motores de datos, ya que la pregunta no indica un motor, no es mala idea indicar para qué motor es la respuesta.

Comment: @jachguate Coloqué los motores en donde estoy seguro que existe. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: En lo personal, evito responder cuando la respuesta es específica de algún motor y la pregunta no lo indica, pues se crea una situación ambigüa. En este caso, seguro que la respuesta es útil para el AP, que ya ni se molestó en editar su pregunta para indicar el motor, y ahora tenemos una buena respuesta a una mala pregunta que solo creará confusión para alguien que llegue aquí en el futuro buscando una respuesta para Firebird, PostgreSQL u otras bases de datos donde no existe la función.